# Why did I get this output while using traceroute with openvpn?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I set up a vpn using `openvpn` command with a certificate bundle downloaded from vpnbook.com. Then when I did `traceroute www.google.com` I got all stars output. I want to know why I got that output.

```
root@kali:~# traceroute www.google.com
traceroute to www.google.com (173.194.120.145), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you get those outputs, it is because the systems contacted by [traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) are not responding with `ICMP Time Exceeded` or `ICMP Echo Reply` messages (or perhaps you are blocking them on your end before they reach you). Traceroute requires systems to send these messages in order to work.

A VPN is designed to extend a LAN to a remote location and to do so in a way that shields the interior packets from the systems in between, so its like you are abstracting away all the networks in between and tracerouting to a system in the same room you are in, which may have only 1 hop.

In this case, You are sending your traffic into an [SSL tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVPN), created between two endpoints. The intermediary systems (IS) between the endpoints can interact with the outside of the tunnel (the packets with SSL encrypted payloads) but cannot interact with the packets/segments inside the tunnel (which is the whole reason you are tunneling in the first place; to do otherwise would be to allow Man-In-The-Middle exploits). These ISs do not have the key. Thus the UDP packets you send in do not get processed and their TTL is not deincremented on each hop, because the IS does not process the packet at all. The packets inside the tunnel experience one hop, no matter how many hops the outer packet takes between endpoints.

The stars indicate a Timeout. Traceroute keeps trying, each time with an incremented TTL, because it expects that some systems won't reply with ICMP, and just keeps running, until it hits its MAX_HOPS (30). I suspect that if the remote endpoint system was configured to respond to UDP TTL expired packets, you would simply see one hop from your endpoint to the remote endpoint, no matter how many ISs the tunnel uses to reach the destination.